# Add custom mime type in Android with storage access framework

Tags: java, android

I want to allow to open only two file types with storage access Framework.
1. *.zip
2. *.ovpn (custom)
The zip file is selectable but the ovpn file is not. How can I get this working?
The Code below only works with zip files:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS));
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");
String[] extraMimeTypes = {"application/zip", "application/ovpn"};
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, extraMimeTypes);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
startActivityForResult(intent, VPN_PROFILES_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Thanks for any assistance.
Marcus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply not possible. A Workaround is checking the Extension later